# How to fix TFS build issue "ResolveComReference" task failed unexpectedly process can't access file System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a WPF solution and I'm using Visual Studio Team Services with TFVC for source control.  I've created an automated build, however, the build will fail (sporadically) with the following error:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (2015, 0)
The "ResolveComReference" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\a\bin\es\System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll' because it is being used by another process.
Server stack trace: 
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.CopyFileWithLogging(FileState sourceFileState, FileState destinationFileState)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.DoCopyWithRetries(FileState sourceFileState, FileState destinationFileState, CopyFileWithState copyFile)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.NativeMethods.QueryPathOfRegTypeLib(Guid& clsid, Int16 majorVersion, Int16 minorVersion, Int32 lcid)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ComReference.GetPathOfTypeLib(TaskLoggingHelper log, Boolean silent, TYPELIBATTR& typeLibAttr, String& typeLibPath)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveComReference.ConvertAttrReferencesToComReferenceInfo(List`1 projectRefs, ITaskItem[] typeLibAttrs)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveComReference.Execute()
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__1.MoveNext()
```

When this does occur.. I can queue another build and it will pass.  Does anyone know why this may be happening and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Do you have multiple builds run in parallel?

Comment: Or do you have multiple projects in the solution that using the same reference?

Comment: I don't have multiple builds running in parallel (that I'm aware of).  There are multiple projects in the solution but only one WPF project that has a direct reference to System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll

Comment: Which build system are you using? Xaml Or vNext?